# Add Menu in WordPress Admin

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to add a top level menu to the left sidebar of the WordPress admin panel.

Here's the code I currently have:

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'linked_url' );
function linked_url() {
add_menu_page( 'linked_url', 'Menu Title', 'read', 'my_slug', '', 'dashicons-text', 1 );
}

add_action( 'admin_menu' , 'linkedurl_function' );
function linkedurl_function() {
global $menu;
$menu[1][2] = "https://www.example.com";
}
```

This code DOES work and links the menu to an external page (`https://www.example.com`).

I learned how to do this from here:  http://www.techedg.com/2014/09/06/5575/a-simple-way-to-add-an-external-link-to-the-wordpress-admin-menu/

However, I can't figure out how to make the external link open in a new tab.  I'd prefer than a new tab/window is opened so people don't lose what they already have open in their admin area.

Is there something I need to change or add?  Or is it just not possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try:

```
add_action( 'admin_menu' , 'linkedurl_function' );
function linkedurl_function() {
global $menu;
$menu[1][2] = "https://www.example.com target=\"_blank";
}
```

So then the opening and closing " (double quotation) tags are already there, and we only need an attribute added, hence we do that by adding to the current string, while escaping the opening double quotation.